# php preg_replace pattern to convert ="xxxxx" to xxxx

Tags: php

I got a few strings,some were started with =" and end with ".

But some  were just an combination with digits and alphabets.

Is there any method to strip the =" and " all at once? Thanks.

```
<?php
     $items = ['0050','="1234P"','123','="2334"'];

    for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++){
         //do something in the "convert" function
         $items[$i]=convert($items[$i]);
    }
    //output: ['0050','1234P','123','2334'];
?>
```

Comment: Yes. Do you have any specific problem with regex?

Comment: Why use regexp? `function convert($value) { return trim($value,'="'); }` or skip calling convert, and just do the trim directly on each element

Comment: The [second parameter to `trim()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) is a character list of characters you would like to trim off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `preg_replace();`

```
$items = array('0050','="1234P"','123','="2334"');

$result = preg_replace("/[=\"]/", "", $items);

print_r($result);
```